# horizontal scroll with inline children

Tags: html, css

So, here be my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HQVs7/

What I have is:

#container div, with a fixed width and height.

#content ul, a list that holds potentially infinite children.

.child li, that need to display inline horizontally (forcing a scroll on the container)

The issue I'm having is in making the ul have the same width as all its children combined inline (side by side), WITHOUT having a set width on it.

I could use jquery, but Im trying to minimise unnecessary scripting if I can accomplish this with css alone.

So simply put, looking at the blue boxes in the jsfiddle (list items), they are currently dropping onto the next line; I need them to be all on the one line, with their parent (#content) expanding with them, without setting a width on the ul.

Any thoughts?

html:

```
<div id="container">
    <ul id="content">
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
        <li class="child"></li>
    </ul>    
</div>
```

css:

```
#container{
    width:600px;
    height: 150px;
    border: solid 1px black;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    overflow-x: scroll;
}

#content{
    display: block;
    height: 150px;
 }

.child{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 2px;
    background-color: #00F;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `white-space:nowrap;` to `#container`

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pph2f/)

[**More from MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

> nowrap: Collapses whitespace as for normal, but suppresses line breaks
>   (text wrapping) within text.

As inline elements are handled similar to text, they arent wrapped to a new line with this applied.

Comment: You're a blessing Sir, many thanks.
Also, I appreciate the explanation!